# Chef Keep Locally Installed Version

Tags: chef-infra, apt

When running an update, how does one select "Keep Locally Installed Version" of configuration files?

I have to manually log in to the server, run updates, and select the option.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when using the `package` resource, Chef should be setting the non-interactive mode on all `apt` commands. Can you be more specific about the error case? If you're using `apt` yourself in `execute` resources or similar, you might have to add `-y` to the command line or `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to the environment (or both).

Comment: well, no -

just apt running the normal update/upgrade on node bootstrap

there is a package that asks if I want to install the package maintainer's version or keep local config (or view side-by-side, etc)

Comment: Define "normal upgrade process"? Do you mean you have `execute 'apt-get upgrade'` in your recipe code?

Comment: I don't, but chef does. that's part of the apt-package recipe

Comment: Chef doesn't come with any recipes, your recipe code is up to you. As I said, any use of `apt` in that kind of execution context will need some settings to be non-interactive.